# Tratar un mensaje de entrada con "emojis"

Tags: python, telegram

Tengo un bot en Telegram escrito en Python que procesa los mensajes que recibe. Una de las funciones es escribir el mensaje en un fichero de texto "log.txt" e imprimirlo en la consola.

Durante varios días funcionó bien hasta que alguien introdujo emoticonos en el texto y el bot se cae.

Tengo la cabeza loca de todo lo que he leido y de aplicar las mil cosas que recomiendan por ahí. Tengo UTF-8 en todas las variables y en el texto del programa, por si alguien piensa que me falta.

La soluciones parece que apuntan a bien:

- Convertir el texto
- Hacer que el sistema tolere este tipo de información
- Directamente eliminar los emojis del mensaje.

El código es muy sencillo, pero aún así lo pongo:

```
 f = open('log.txt', 'a')
 f.write(mensaje + "\n")
 f.close()
 print (mensaje)
```

Cuando intento imprimir un mensaje que contiene Emojis en el IDLE obtengo el siguiente error

> UnicodeEncodeError: 'UCS-2' codec can't encode characters in position 46-46: Non-BMP character not supported in Tk

Comment: Ramon faltan muchos detalles a la pregunta auque no lo parexca. Primero ¿Python 2 o Python 3?, segundo ¿que tipo de variable es mensaje?¿Que se recibe de telegram, con que codificación?¿Es una cadena unicode con codificación utf-8?¿Son bytes/str? ¿Que obtines si haces print(repr(mensaje))? ¿Podrias mostrar el error concreto que obtienes? Con la información que proporcionas es difícil dar de primeras una posible solución. en principio no debes tener problemas para imprimir (con una terminal con la codificación apropiada) o guardar emogis en un fichero.

Comment: Un ejemplo: https://repl.it/LrqG/0. Lo mas importante es que muestres lo que recibes de telegram tal cual, `print(repr(mensaje_crudo))`  y `print(type(mensaje_crudo))` mostrando lo que se recibe con un mensaje con emoji, serian de ayuda y un punto de partida. Luego ya depende de que quieras hacer, si guardarlos como tal con codificación apropiada, escaparlos, eliminarlos, etc. Un saludo.

Comment: 1) Pythón 3.6.2. 2) Mensaje es una variable de texto, de hecho valido que if mensaje == 'text'.  3) No se que se con que codificación se reciben las cosas. 4) print(repr(mensaje))
UnicodeEncodeError: 'UCS-2' codec can't encode characters in position 46-46: Non-BMP character not supported in Tk

Comment: Estas usando casi seguro el IDLE y recibes caracteres unicode fuera del BMP (> 0xFFFF). Puedes escaparlos, por ejemplo `print(mensaje.encode("unicode_escape"))` no debe darte error o sustituirlos haciendo algo como se muestra en https://stackoverflow.com/a/32442684/7131499. Tambien puedes usar una terminal que soporte estos caracteres. Comenta a ver si llegamos a algun lado... XD

Comment: Perfecto: "mensaje.encode("unicode_escape")". Muchas gracias.

Comment: He de decir, que entre las decenas de cosas que he probado, esta era una de ellas y que efectivamente estaba usando IDLE, ahora lo he hecho con Pycharm.No se que estaba haciendo mal pero el caso es que me tenía loco. Gracias de nuevo, era mi primer programa en Python

Answer (score 3):

Aparentemente recibes mensajes con codificación  UTF-8 que es lo que retorna [`telegram.message.text`](https://python-telegram-bot.readthedocs.io/en/stable/telegram.message.html#Message.text), de la biblioteca *python-telegram-bot* (que supongo que usas).

El problema con los Emojis es que son caracteres definidos fuera del primer plano Unicode (Plano 0 o *Basic_Multilingual_Plane*) con valores entre 0000 y FFFF. Los Emojis se sitúan en el Plano 1 o *Supplementary Multilingual Plane* junto a otros símbolos como notaciones musicales o matemáticas.

Un ejemplo de cadena que puedes recibir es

```
s = "Yo \U0001F497 \U0001F40D...\U0001F601 y las cigüeñas."
```

Que codificada (UTF-8) seria

```
b'Yo \xf0\x9f\x92\x97 \xf0\x9f\x90\x8d...\xf0\x9f\x98\x81 y las cig\xc3\xbce\xc3\xb1as.'
```

Correctamente impresa seria

> Yo  ... y las cigüeñas.

Tkinter, framework sobre el que se construye el IDLE, no soporta caracteres fuera del plano 0, de ahí el error obtenido al intentar imprimir en el IDLE:

> UnicodeEncodeError: 'UCS-2' codec can't encode characters in position 46-46: Non-BMP character not supported in Tk

También tendrás problemas con CMD, que tiene por lo general mal soporte para caracteres no BMP. Si tu CMD/PowerShell tiene el mapa por defecto (como CP850) directamente tendrás un error  del tipo:

> UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode character '\U0001f601' in position 11: character maps to < undefined >

Con otros mapas como CP65001 no obtendrás el error pero si la fuente no soporta estos caracteres no se mostrara correctamente.

Con una terminal/emulador de terminal que use codificación Unicode para stdout junto a una fuente con soporte para estos caracteres podrás imprimirlo sin problemas. Por ejemplo en Konsole (KDE):

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Una posible solución si no se puede configurar o usar una terminal con este soporte es  eliminar estos caracteres directamente. Hay varias formas de hacerlo (se puede hacer algo como lo propuesto por  Martijn Pieters en su [respuesta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32442684/7131499)  a un problema similar en SO usando `str.translate`), una muy simples es:

```
>>> import unicodedata
>>> s = "Yo \U0001F497 \U0001F40D...\U0001F601 y las cigüeñas."
>>> print(''.join(c for c in unicodedata.normalize('NFC', s) if c <= '\uFFFF' ))
Yo  ... y las cigüeñas.
```

Esto deja el string sin mucho sentido, posiblemente sea mejor sustituir los Emojis por otro carácter valido, generalmente �.

```
>>> import unicodedata
>>> s = "Yo \U0001F497 \U0001F40D...\U0001F601 y las cigüeñas."
>>> print(''.join(c if c <= '\uFFFF' else '\uFFFD' for c in unicodedata.normalize('NFC', s)))
Yo � �...� y las cigüeñas.
```

A unas malas o con fines de debugging se puede también codificar la cadena e imprimir el bytearray:

```
print(s.encode())
print(s.encode("unicode_escape"))
```

A la hora de guardar el archivo de log lo ideal es guardar el string tal cual o a lo sumo con los caracteres unicode escapados. De esta forma no perdemos la información de los Emojis:

```
with open("log.txt", "a", encoding="utf-8") as f:
    f.write(s + "\n")
```

Siempre recordando que de imprimir su contenido en la terminal hay que proceder igual que antes.