# Error con UCS-2 , al recorrer pagina web con python y selenium

Tags: python, selenium

tengo este error al recorrer la pagina obteniendo links, va todo ok hasta que llega a este titulo ⚠️Warning Games , como podria hacer para que no me marque error que es por el signo amarillo.
este es el error que me obtengo:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "C:\Users\xxxxx\Desktop\scrap\extnum.py", line 41, in 
>       print("{}".format(div.text)) UnicodeEncodeError: 'UCS-2' codec can't encode characters in position 18-18: Non-BMP character not
>   supported in Tk

Gracias

Comment: ¿Estás ejecutando el código en el IDLE por casualidad? Tkinter no soporta caracteres fuera del [BMP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plane_(Unicode)#Basic_Multilingual_Plane), como los emojis, por eso el error. Si es así, mírate https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/106231/tratar-un-mensaje-de-entrada-con-emojis/106429#106429

Comment: Respondida en el link del comentario, garcias